# Atualizar página de forma Simples

Tags: html

Tenho uma zona no meu site em que tem as ultimas 5 novidades e quero colocar uma forma de alterar isto sem ser manualmente. 
nem que seja com um ficheiro Excel, bloco de notas o que for.

```
   <div id="footer-wrapper">
            <section id="footer" class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="8u">
                        <section>
                            <header>
                                <h2>Últimas Noticias:</h2>
                            </header>
                            <ul class="dates">
                              <li>
                                    <span class="date">jan <strong>31</strong></span>
                                    <h3><a href="#">TESTE</a></h3>
                                    <p>Ipsum dolor sit amet veroeros consequat blandit ipsum phasellus lorem consequat etiam.</p>
                                </li>
                              <li>
                                    <span class="date">Jan <strong>23</strong></span>
                                    <h3><a href="#">Teste</a></h3>
                                    <p>Blandit phasellus lorem ipsum dolor tempor sapien tortor hendrerit adipiscing feugiat lorem.</p>
                                </li>
                              <li>
                                    <span class="date">Jan <strong>1</strong></span>
                                    <h3><a href="#">Ano Novo</a></h3>
                                    <p>Dolore consequat sed phasellus lorem sed etiam nullam dolor etiam sed amet sit consequat.</p>
                                </li>
                              <li>
                                    <span class="date">Dez <strong>25</strong></span>
                                    <h3><a href="#">Dia de Natal</a></h3>
                                    <p>Feugiat lorem dolor sed nullam tempus lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nullam consequat.</p>
                                </li>
                              <li>
                                    <span class="date">Dez <strong>13</strong></span>
                                    <h3><a href="#">teste</a></h3>
                                    <p>Feugiat sed tempus blandit tempus adipiscing nisl lorem ipsum dolor sit amet dolore.</p>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </section>
```

Comment: Que tal fazer um mini backoffice em PHP + HTML para alterar esses campos?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, cria uma pagina qualquer com o conteudo a ser atualizado, dentro dela acrescente:

```
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
     </head>
```

e na pagina principal acrescente um iframe chamando a pagina do conteudo na região do site que tu querer

Comment: O problema do meta refresh é que ele irá atualizar a página toda e não apenas a parte de notícias.

Comment: errado moço, o refresh vai estar na pagina separada, nao vai alterar o conteudo da pagina principal, somente o iframe. faça o teste. alem o mais a solução seria simples, conforme foi solicitado.

Comment: Tá certo. não tinha lido que você escreveu para usar o iframe. Desculpe.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria você utilizar websockets para resposta em tempo real mas se quiser fazer uma atualização a cada minuto você poderá usar a função setInterval() do javascript e configurar para fazer uma chamada ajax a cada minuto e atualizar um `<div>` ou a própria `<ul>` com o conteúdo retornado.

```
setInterval(function(){ /* chamada ajax aqui */ }, 60000);
```

Comment: PHP Long Polling seria melhor uma vez que seria uma requisição até ter uma resposta do servidor, enquanto com a solução proposta acima teria que fazer requisições mesmo que não haja nenhuma resposta.

Comment: O ideal seria o web socket. o long polling é uma forma de simular um web socket e é utilizado em navegadores que não suportam o html 5. Obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: Long Polling com as tecnologias tradicionais que vem nos servidores esgota rapidamente as threads do servidor Web. Acaba se tornando um problema maior do que o "peso" do Ajax bem rápido.